# Laravel 5 complex AND WHERE query not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have a issue with the following code:

```
            $clients_counter = 0;
            $cost = 0;

            $query = DB::table('clientes')->where('recibe_sms', '=', '1')
            ->where(function($q)
            {
                $q->orWhere('movil_1',      '<>', '')
                  ->orWhere('movil_2',      '<>', '')
                  ->orWhere('otro_movil',   '<>', '');

            });

            $with_moto          = (Input::has('moto')) ? 1 : 0;
            $with_coche         = (Input::has('coche')) ? 1 : 0;
            $with_camion        = (Input::has('camion')) ? 1 : 0;
            $with_autobus       = (Input::has('autobus')) ? 1 : 0;
            $with_tractor       = (Input::has('tractor')) ? 1 : 0;
            $with_maquinaria    = (Input::has('maquinaria')) ? 1 : 0;
            $with_furgoneta     = (Input::has('furgoneta')) ? 1 : 0;
            $with_taxi          = (Input::has('taxi')) ? 1 : 0;


            $query = $query->where(function($q) use ($with_moto,$with_coche,$with_camion,$with_autobus,$with_tractor,$with_maquinaria,$with_furgoneta,$with_taxi)
            {
                $q->where('moto',       '=', $with_moto)
                  ->where('coche',      '=', $with_coche)
                  ->where('camion',     '=', $with_camion)
                  ->where('autobus',    '=', $with_autobus)
                  ->where('tractor',    '=', $with_tractor)
                  ->where('maquinaria', '=', $with_maquinaria)
                  ->where('furgoneta',  '=', $with_furgoneta)
                  ->where('taxi',       '=', $with_taxi);

            });



            $count = $query->count();

            $clients_counter = $count;
            $cost = $clients_counter * 0.08;

            $response = [

                'counter'   => $clients_counter,
                'cost'      => $cost,
                'inputed'   => Input::all()

            ];

            return $response;
```

The $with_moto, $with_coche ...  $with_taxi corresponds to checkboxes on my form. If I check one by one (I mean only one to be checked) I get correct results.

For example if I check $with_moto I get 2 results and if I check $with_coche I get 1 result. What I need to achieve is to get 3 results when I check both of them.

All this field are tinyint(1) with values 1 or 0.

I tried a lot to figure out how to solve this but I am missing something.

This is a SQL Query that I use manually against SQL Server and I get correct results:

> SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE (movil_1 != "" OR movil_2
>   != "" OR otro_movil != "") AND (recibe_sms = '1') AND ((moto = '1') OR
>   (coche = '1') OR (camion = '1') OR (autobus = '1') OR (tractor = '1')
>   OR (maquinaria = '1') OR (furgoneta = '1') OR (taxi = '1'));

Maybe somebody can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please ask the question.

Comment: you are searching for `orWhere` instead of `where`

Comment: I tried to explain what I need to achieve below the code. If I check one checkbox (moto) I get 2 results and if I check other checkbox (for example 'coche') I get 1 result. How should I make the query to get 3 results

Comment: @vitaminasweb read my comment above

Comment: @kmlnvm the part with orWhere it's ok. First I check if there is at least one mobile phone number (movil = mobile in spanish) ... I updated the question adding a sql raw ...

Comment: can you print out the query laravel is generating?

Comment: I just saw your comment! I already solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the code as following:

```
        $clients_counter = 0;           $cost = 0;

        $query = DB::table('clientes')->where('recibe_sms', '=', '1')           ->where(function($q)            {
            $q->orWhere('movil_1',      '<>', '')
              ->orWhere('movil_2',      '<>', '')
              ->orWhere('otro_movil',   '<>', '');

        });

        $i = [];

        $i['with_moto']         = (Input::has('moto')) ? true : false;          $i['with_coche']        = (Input::has('coche')) ? true : false;             $i['with_camion']       = (Input::has('camion')) ? true : false;            $i['with_autobus']      = (Input::has('autobus')) ? true : false;           $i['with_tractor']      = (Input::has('tractor')) ? true : false;           $i['with_maquinaria']   = (Input::has('maquinaria')) ? true : false;            $i['with_furgoneta']    = (Input::has('furgoneta')) ? true : false;             $i['with_taxi']         = (Input::has('taxi')) ? true : false;

                    $query = $query->where(function($q) use ($i)            {

            if ($i['with_moto']) $q->orWhere('moto',                '=', $i['with_moto']);
            if ($i['with_coche']) $q->orWhere('coche',              '=', $i['with_coche']);
            if ($i['with_camion']) $q->orWhere('camion',            '=', $i['with_camion']);
            if ($i['with_autobus']) $q->orWhere('autobus',          '=', $i['with_autobus']);
            if ($i['with_tractor']) $q->orWhere('tractor',          '=', $i['with_tractor']);
            if ($i['with_maquinaria']) $q->orWhere('maquinaria',    '=', $i['with_maquinaria']);
            if ($i['with_furgoneta']) $q->orWhere('furgoneta',      '=', $i['with_furgoneta']);
            if ($i['with_taxi']) $q->orWhere('taxi',                '=', $i['with_taxi']);

        });
                    $count = $query->count();

        $clients_counter = $count;          $cost = $clients_counter * 0.08;

        $response = [

            'counter'   => $clients_counter,
            'cost'      => $cost,
            'inputed'   => Input::all()

        ];

        return $response;
```